# Bash: how to pipe each result of one command to another

Tags: bash, pipe

I want to get the **total** count of the number of lines from all the files returned by the following command:

```
shell> find . -name *.info
```

All the .info files are nested in sub-directories so I can't simply do:

```
shell> wc -l *.info
```

Am sure this should be in any bash users repertoire, but am stuck!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wc -l `find . -name *.info`
```

If you just want the total, use

```
wc -l `find . -name *.info` | tail -1
```

---

Edit: Piping to `xargs` also works, and hopefully can avoid the 'command line too long'.

```
find . -name *.info | xargs wc -l
```

Comment: ah of course back ticks. marking you correct for being the most simple/elegant solution

Comment: Hope you don't have too many files. Beware the dreaded "command line too long"

Comment: @Adrian: yes - I had not considered that, so maybe not the "right" answer after all. (Although works for me: 2,500 files)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xargs` like so:

```
find . -name *.info -print0 | xargs -0 cat | wc -l
```

Comment: Don't forget to quote your shell meta-characters or else you might wonder why you're getting odd results or odd errors from find:  find . -name '*.info' -print0 | xargs -0 cat | wc -l

Answer (score 1):

some googling turns up

```
find /topleveldirectory/ -type f -exec wc -l {} \; | awk '{total += $1} END{print total}'
```

which seems to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
# bash 4.0
shopt -s globstar
sum=0
for file in **/*.info
do
   if [ -f "$file" ];then
       s=$(wc -l< "$file")
       sum=$((sum+s))
   fi
done
echo "Total: $sum"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "*.info" -exec wc -l {} \;
```

Note to self - read the question

```
find . -name "*.info" -exec cat {} \; | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# for a speed-up use: find ... -exec ... '{}' + | ...
find . -type f -name "*.info" -exec sed -n '$=' '{}' + | awk '{total += $0} END{print total}'
```