# How to pipe in the result of another UNIX command

Tags: unix, tr

Right now I'm using another text file to store the result of one UNIX command and then using that file to run another command, like so:

```
tr -d "[,|.]" < text > temporary.txt
tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" < temporary.txt > result.txt
```

How do I combine these two into a single line so that I don't have to use a temporary file? The following does not work:

```
(tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" < (tr -d "[,|.]" < text)) > result.txt
```

I know how to use && but that still requires the use of a temporary holder file.

Possible duplicate: [Bash: how to pipe each result of one command to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404946/bash-how-to-pipe-each-result-of-one-command-to-another)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pipes are your friend:-

```
cat text | tr -d "[,|.]" | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" >result.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

1. `tr -d "[,|.]" < text | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" > result.txt`
2. `cat text | tr -d "[,|.]" | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" > result.txt`

Both commands do the same job.

What pipe(designated by `|`) does, is just redirects output of one command to the input of another. So, for example, in `foo | bar` the output of `foo` gets redirected into input of `bar`.